# Delete a Row when the Column has the same value in the next ROW

Tags: vba

Can Any one give a macro or VBA code or idea how to start ...
and i have a example below posted .. but in Real my EXL tabel is huge ..

What I have in my column:
1
2
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
3
4
3
4
4
4
5
5
3
4
4
3
4
4
4
2
3
4
4
4
4
4
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
3

What I need as result

1
2
3
4
3
4
3
4
5
3
4
3
4
2
3
4

All I want is to delete the row

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO Is not a "Code for Me", "Teach me to Code", or a "Show where to Start" site. It is a place for those with existing code with specific problems to get specific help on overcoming that problem. If you have code that you have tried that is not working please put it in your original post using edit and explain what the code is doing in error. As is, this is too broad for this forum and risks down votes and closure.

Comment: ThanX for your comments ...

Comment: Try to record some macros and look at the code. Try some other code you find on the topic "delete row when condition "x" is met". Make a test sheet with a single cell and try to delete it with vba. Post your code if you get stuck along the way.

Comment: cant really get a idea how to start ...

Comment: [This](http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/automating-excel/1264-getting-started.html) is the first link that popped up when I google "How to start with VBA in Excel. It should give you a good start!

Comment: I cant get a solution for my question ... I know how google works .. I am looking for how to approach for this question ...

Comment: If you google for "excel delete consecutive duplicates" you will find several example codes like [that](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=397989) which will be a good start.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821382.aspx

Comment: This helped me for a start ... ThanX Peh !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

It compares the value of the next row to the value of the selected row and deletes the entire next row if both values are the same.

Note the list should not contain any blank cells.

```
Public Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        With ActiveCell
            'Compare next row value against selected row value
            If .Offset(1, 0).Value <> .Value Then
                'Value not the same - jump to it
                .Offset(1, 0).Select
            Else
                'Value the same - delete entire next row
                .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        End With
    Loop

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Edit:

```
Public Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        With ActiveCell
            If .Offset(1, 0).Value = .Value And .Offset(1, 1).Value = 0 Then
                .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
            Else
                .Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        End With
    Loop

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for ... but .. I have a small problem .... In  a next column i have values from 0 to 10  and I do not want to delete if the value is above zero.  How do i ADD this in the code ?

Comment: U saved my day ... Thank you ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Loop on every cells of a range and check if the value of cell(A,i) and cell(A,i-1) are the same where i is the iterator.